# how to get invite names or email instead of EventGuest?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Below i have put my code to retrieve info from my google calendar. Butr because i am a noob in this i get stuck. can anyone help me to retrieve email adress, or namems of the guest.

```
function getEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("###");
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("06/01/2020 12:00 AM"), new Date("06/30/2030 12:00 AM"));
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(2, 1, lr - 1, 6).clearContent();
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    var sd = events[i].getStartTime();
    var ed = events[i].getEndTime();
    var loc = events[i].getLocation();
    var des = events[i].getDescription();
    var guest = events[i].getGuestList();
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 1).setValue(title);
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue(sd);
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 2).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy /hh:mm");
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 3).setValue(ed);
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 3).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy /hh:mm");
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue(loc);
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 5).setValue(des);
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(guest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using nodejs? How does an example response object look like?

Comment: nodejs? i have no clue what that is, i want my data from my calendar brought into my app sheet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384176/how-can-i-specify-the-guest-status-so-it-will-put-the-names-in-the-right-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `getGuestList()` is a resource from which you can extract information such as invitee emails by iterating through the guest list

Therefore modify

```
    var guest = events[i].getGuestList();
    ss.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(guest);
```

to

```
   var guests = events[i].getGuestList();
   var guestEmails = "";
   for (var j = 0; j < guests.length; j++) {
     var guest = guests[j].getEmail();
     guestEmails += guest+", ";
   }
   ss.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(guestEmails);
```

Comment: Dear ziganotschka, Thanks for your help. Now i see a email adress. But i just get 1 email adress, not all my invited guests. Is there something wrong in the code? or did i set the wrong values\

Comment: i have to find out how to activate the log to the logfile

Comment: Implement in your code `Logger.log(guests.length)` and see the log by going to `View`->`Logs`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) for more information.

Comment: I did what you told me but i just get this in my log                                                   
[20-04-21 14:40:58:101 CEST] 0.0
[20-04-21 14:40:58:181 CEST] 1.0
[20-04-21 14:40:58:256 CEST] 0.0
[20-04-21 14:40:58:341 CEST] 0.0
[20-04-21 14:40:58:423 CEST] 0.0
[20-04-21 14:40:58:517 CEST] 0.0
[20-04-21 14:40:58:598 CEST] 5.0
[20-04-21 14:40:58:665 CEST] 0.0

Comment: i can see 5 participants on my log but still have one email adres. I am so srry that i am such a noob and dont fully understand what i do wrong. i want to thank you ziganotschka, that you take the time to help me.

Comment: [20-04-21 14:40:58:598 CEST] 5.0

Comment: Thanks man, i just forgot a bracket in my line. I now have all the names of my inviteds. Now i have to find out how the code can separate the attendees from the decliners

Comment: As for the guest status, you can use the method `getGuestStatus()` inside an `if` statement to decide to chich string / array to append the email address. I suggest you to try it, and if you encounter issues - post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, as for the guest status i wil search for the correct code. if i cant find the right way I will post a new question. Thanks again.