# Google Script to return calendar guest names (only) into one cell separated by comma

Tags: google-apps-script

I need help adjusting the script to return the calendar guest names only (not email) and put the names into 1 cell with each name separated by a comma.

I found a script that does this with the guests email, but I cannot figure out how to edit the script to return Names only. Here is the spreadsheet:

[Daily Reminders](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/190dZAqnQ_vrj9CGnp9y7jFyPSjWXRWW7wIU1HCPpSqA/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for taking a look.

I have spent 3 days working on this. First I [watched this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYmdsOvUOng) to learn to get the event, then had to [read this previous, similar, but not really!, solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338625/how-to-get-invite-names-or-email-instead-of-eventguest) and have played with, and [read this App Script Developer Site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar) for 3 days until I figured out how to get the emails.

---

```
function getTomorrowEvents() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tomorrow");

  var start_time = sheet.getRange("b2").getValue();
  var end_time = sheet.getRange("d2").getValue();
  var id_cal = sheet.getRange("B1:F1").getValue();

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id_cal);
    var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(start_time), new Date(end_time));

  for (var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
    
    var title =  events[i].getTitle();
    var start_time =  events[i].getStartTime();
    var end_time =  events[i].getEndTime();
    var loc = events[i].getLocation();
    var des =  events[i].getDescription();
    var guests = events[i].getGuestList();
    var guestEmails = "";
     for (var j = 0; j < guests.length; j++) {
     var guest = guests[j].getEmail();
     guestEmails += guest+", ";
   }
    
    sheet.getRange(i+4,2).setValue(title);
    sheet.getRange(i+4,3).setValue(start_time);
    sheet.getRange(i+4,4).setValue(end_time);
    sheet.getRange(i+4,5).setValue(loc);
    sheet.getRange(i+4,6).setValue(des);
    sheet.getRange(i+4,7).setValue(guestEmails);

  }
  Logger.log("Events have been added to the Spreadsheet");
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expected as the image?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I have this document with maybe a better description of the script help needed. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ivNIGcouWGwlxhQi9zuBW15L_ZmGFd_mm_49fD8Le4U/edit?usp=sharing. 

and I made a short (2 min) video. Illustrating (maybe this will help you understand the spreadsheet better). https://drive.google.com/file/d/15nSutoNK3CKkyVAm6-uC6w3VGhJ4tH1m/view?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, about `guestEmails` in your showing script, you want to retrieve the user's name instead of the email. Is my underrstanding correct? By guessing your goal, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- About `guestEmails` in your showing script, you want to retrieve the user's name instead of the email address.

#### Issue and workaround:

- When I saw `getName()` of Class EventGuest, it says `the guest's name, or the guest's email address if the name is not available`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getName())
- When I saw `attendees[].displayName` of Event of Calendar API, it says `The attendee's name, if available.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#attendees)

When I tested `getName()` in my calendar, no value is returned. Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure about your actual calendar, if you can retrieve the user's name, you can achieve your goal by the following modification.

- From

  ```
    var guest = guests[j].getEmail();
  ```
- To

  ```
    var guest = guests[j].getName();
  ```

If this modification was not the direct solution to your situation, it is required to convert the email address to the user's name. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, ContactsApp is used for converting the email address to the name.

##### From:

```
var guest = guests[j].getEmail();
```

##### To:

```
var guest = ContactsApp.getContact(guests[j].getEmail()).getFullName();
```

- Or, I think that you can also use People API as follows. Before you use this script, [please enable People API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

  - From

    ```
      for (var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){

        var title =  events[i].getTitle();
        var start_time =  events[i].getStartTime();
        var end_time =  events[i].getEndTime();
        var loc = events[i].getLocation();
        var des =  events[i].getDescription();
        var guests = events[i].getGuestList();
        var guestEmails = "";
         for (var j = 0; j < guests.length; j++) {
         var guest = guests[j].getEmail();
         guestEmails += guest+", ";
       }
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var res = People.People.Connections.list("people/me", { personFields: "emailAddresses,names", pageSize: 1000 });
      var obj = res.connections.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.emailAddresses[0].value] = e.names ? e.names[0].displayName : e.emailAddresses[0].value, o), {});
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var title = events[i].getTitle();
        var start_time = events[i].getStartTime();
        var end_time = events[i].getEndTime();
        var loc = events[i].getLocation();
        var des = events[i].getDescription();
        var guests = events[i].getGuestList();
        var guestEmails = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < guests.length; j++) {
          var guest = obj[guests[j].getEmail()] || guests[j].getEmail();
          guestEmails += guest + ", ";
        }
    ```

#### References:

- [getContact(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactemailaddress)
- [Method: people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)

Comment: Changing the var guest to this:

var guest = ContactsApp.getContact(guests[j].getEmail()).getFullName();

worked perfectly. Thank you so much. 
You are a genius!

Comment: @Darrell Ellis Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.